# ¿Cuál es la forma segura de instalar matplotlib en Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hola estoy tratando de reinstalar las librerías de Python en mi maquina y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Cuando intento instalar matplotlib por medio de pip install matploblib y corro el siguiente código para verificar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

me sale este error:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
_check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

Comment: Pip no es apropiado para instalar binarios en windows. ¿Tuviste algún error al instalar matplotlib?¿Te pidió algún entorno de desarrollo para compilar el código fuente? Mi recomendación es que uses conda.

Comment: existe otro codigo entonces?

Comment: he usado pip se instala si, pero no escribo un programa y cuando lo corro en mi terminal me sale esa notificación

Comment: Según sea el módulo, pip puede necesitar compilar las librerías a partir de los fuentes. En general, no es nada fácil configurar un entorno de desarrollo python para compilar en windows, por lo que es recomendable que módulos como numpy o matplotlib se instalen usando gestores como conda (anaconda/miniconda).

Answer (score 0):

Primero asegúrate de tenerlo instalado. Para instalarlo, ve a tu terminal y pon el siguiente código:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Con eso tu codigo deberia funcionar si lo instalaste dentro del mismo entorno. Sin embargo, si estas usando `Jupiter` asegurate de tener la siguiente linea en la celda donde vayas a usar la libreria:

```
%matplotlib inline
```